# Many-to-Many Relationships: Querying for Objects with a Single Value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models. An `Artist` model, and a `Album` model. There's a `ManyToManyField` connecting the two, since an album can have more than one artist (collaborations and the like).

The problem I'm having is when I do a simple `Album.objects.filter(artists=1)`-type query, it expectedly shows all of the `Album` objects that have that artist attributed to it. What I want to do is find all of the albums where that artist is the only artist (their releases, no collaborations).

(I'm not familiar with the `extra()` clause, but I'm sure it might have something to do with the solution to this, so any help on that end is much appreciated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Album.objects.annotate(n_artists=Count("artists')).filter(n_artists=1).filter(artist=some_awesome_artist)
```

Basically the idea is to find all the albums who have exactly 1 artist (by annotating and filtering), and then filter down.